# Eclipse double-click line number for breakpoint

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

This is probably one of the more silly questions you find on StackOverflow, but I truely cannot find the problem here.

I run Eclipse 3.7.2 (I20110613-1736) (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS version). After recent updates, my `org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature` projects don't **toggle breakpoints when double-clicking** on line numbers anymore. Instead, it makes a bookmark and asks me to enter a bookmark-name.

Breakpoints work fine though, and I can add them using `Ctrl+Shift+B`, but after years of habit, I keep making bookmarks because I want to double-click.

The `General` -> `Keys` preferences dialog doesn't have an option for assigning mouseclicks (AFAIK), so it doesn't look like those settings have changed.

Comment: One eclipse bug seems relevant https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=239317.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I experienced the same problem and found my answer here:
[Can't set breakpoints in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664851/cant-set-breakpoints-in-eclipse)

For some reason my file opened with eclipse's plain text editor. I closed my file, right-clicked on it in Package Explorer --> Open With --> Java Editor, and breakpoints work as normal again.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'll accept your answer because I cannot verify it anymore. I have new software versions and breakpoints work normally now.

Answer (score 1):

just edit something in the file (add a space, delete that space, and then save the file). Toggle breakpoints will work again.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happening sometimes for me too, but I haven't figured out in what conditions. You can just right-click on a line number and select the Toggle Breakpoint in the context menu that is opened.

Comment: Actually, I don't have it in the context menu either. Only `Ctrl+Shift+B` works. But if I remember correctly, I _used_ to have it in there also. Maybe they both disappeared at the same time.

Comment: It's possible to be some bug in the bundle handling that features.