# setOnClickListener not responding

Tags: android, android-listview

I found my answer in my recent post but now something is gaining focus of my listview so I when I try to click on a which list item I want to select nothing happens. I had did some research and learned that something takes focus of the activity when this happens and the only thing I can think of that is causing this is my scollview.  I have tried putting `android:focusable="false">` in my xml file under my scrollview but I still get the same results. So I'm just hoping somebody can give me some advice

ListActivity:

```
public class List extends ListActivity {    


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;        

     final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
     static final String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
     final String TAG_QUESTION = "question";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
     final String TAG_ANSWERS = "Answers";
     final String TAG_ANSWER = "Answer";    
     final String TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT = "content";      
     final String TAG_QUERY = "query";

            JSONArray question = null;          

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //setContentView(R.layout.listview);        

        questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

      new LoadAllData().execute();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == 100) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ProgressDialog pDialog; 
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                Intent in = getIntent();
                String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/questionSearch?appid=4vCW8F3V34GzdMlXOS.yc2WfF5DCnCgqhK0nwCJmEFDgRwEbIgnAoEgJ0zynqOAWtQ&query="+ query +"&search_in=question&sort=relevance&results=25&output=json";
                JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                try {
                    //question = json.getJSONArray(TAG_QUESTION);


                    JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

                    for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


                    String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                    String NumAnswers = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS);
                    String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                    String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                    //JSONArray Answers = question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS).getJSONArray(TAG_ANSWER);


                    //JSONObject Answer = Answers.getJSONObject(0);

                    //String Content = Answer.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);

                               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS, NumAnswers);

                               questionList.add(map);


                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                return TAG_QUESTION     ; 



        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                        R.layout.listview,
                        new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS }, new int[] {
                        R.id.Subject, R.id.NumAnswers });

                setListAdapter(adapter);

                android.widget.ListView lv = getListView();

                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {                    

                        String Subject = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Subject)).getText().toString();
                        String Content = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Content)).getText().toString();
                        String ChosenAnswer = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.ChosenAnswer)).getText().toString();


                        Intent i = new Intent(ListView.this, SingleListItem.class);
                        i.putExtra("TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT", Subject);
                        i.putExtra("TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT", Content);
                        i.putExtra("TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER", ChosenAnswer);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }   

                });     

        }}

    }
```

list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Subject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/NumAnswers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ChosenAnswer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/Content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:focusable="false">
    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try putting your listener to a variable before adding them to the list. like OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {}; list.addOnClickListener(listener). Because inline listener as you did can be garbage collected to early ;)

Comment: Tell me when it worked. THen i can add it as answer

Comment: Where do you think is the proper place to put this line of code

Comment: can you put this code in an example for ne

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `listener` outside of the `AsyncTask`. Make it a member variable and initialize it in `onCreate()`

```
public class List extends ListActivity {    

ListView lv;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;        

 ...       

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    //setContentView(R.layout.listview);        

    questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {                    

           String Subject = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Subject)).getText().toString();
           String Content = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Content)).getText().toString();
           String ChosenAnswer = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.ChosenAnswer)).getText().toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(ListView.this, SingleListItem.class);
            i.putExtra("TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT", Subject);
            i.putExtra("TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT", Content);
            i.putExtra("TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER", ChosenAnswer);
            startActivity(i);
          }   

     });     

  new LoadAllData().execute();
```

Your `AscncTask` is finishing so your `listener` is probably not around anymore. You can still set your `Adapter` there just move the `onItemClick()` and the initialization.

**Edit**

Since its `ListActivity` you don't need to set the listener on it. Just implement the method

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
     // do your work
}
```

Comment: it still has the same results

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in there to make sure it isn't getting called?

Comment: If using Eclipse you double click on in the left margin where you want to place one. Then click debug and the program will stop at that point if it reaches that line

Comment: [Setting breakpoints in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664851/cant-set-breakpoints-in-eclipse)

Comment: do you think it could be this `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position, long id`

Comment: Yes, try `publicvoid onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` and `setOnListItemClick`

Comment: I get an syntax error underneath `setOnItemClick` that says `The method setOnListItemClick(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}} is undefined for the type ListView`

Comment: Sorry, comment out where you set it and just use the `onListItemClick()` method